# undefined method when trying to access related record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting this error.

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

When I try to access my related model record, like this:

User Model:

```
has_one :facility
```

User Facility:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Facility controller

```
@adminfacilities = Facility.all
```

Index.html.erb

```
@adminfacilities.each do |facility|
  facility.user.email
```

I just don't get what I'm doing wrong here.
Why can't I access such info?

Lots of thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but a little optimization of your code : write `@adminfacilities = Facility.find(:all, :include => :user)` if you know you will access to the `user` reflection of your facilities objets.

Comment: That is right, but I need to go over facilities with no user assigned to it too. Thanksanyway because it's a great tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because some `facility.user` is `nil`, you may use:

```
@adminfacilities.each do |facility|
  facility.user.try(:email)
```

Comment: this works, can you quickly explain why? what does try do? Thx!

Comment: a.try(:method) execute the method if a is not nil, renders nil elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

As xdazz said, your `facility.user` is `nil`.

Maybe you should add a validation in your Facility model

```
validates_presence_of :user
```

And a dependency for destroy

```
belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a `Facility` that **does not have a user assigned to it** in the foreign key, and when the `foreach` loop reaches that facility it finds that there is no user assigned, therefore, it cannot return the user's attribute you are looking for, in this case, `email`.

**Check** your database *Facility* table, there will probably be a `user_id` that is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks okay.

I think the reason is you are using development mode, and have not create correct association data.

Suggest you to check data again to see if any facility record doesn't have user_id.

Also it's strongly recommended to add validation as per ForgetTheNorm said.

Answer (score 0):

some respective Facility don't have user so it is return nil.

Then from user table u or trying to access email. so it through exception of nil:NilClass(User nilclass)

we can write some best understanding code like this

**facility.user ? facility.user.email : nil**  # it will facility user is there if user return then it will give user email else it return nil

(or)

facility.user.try(:email)